# Merging Respective Start and End Dates, Setting Flag Depending on Start/End Date - SQL

Tags: sql, date, merge, teradata

**Problem:**
I have a table of transactions (see below) with either (open/start) or (close/end) transaction in the format of date. The task is to merge these transactions with their corresponding dates, however, there can be also cases when the transaction is opened/started, but not closed/ended, in which case only Start Date must be shown, and the Flag 'Y' assigned. The rest of cases where there is an Enddate, the flag will be 'N'. I have been able to set a flag depending on the values with first_value(Flag IGNORE NULLS) over(partition by Customer_ID order by EndDate desc), but Im having a bit harder time with matching the start with end dates.

**Logic:**

- There can be multiple start & end dates per one day with only time differences.
- There can be just one start & end date transaction per customer per day.
- There can be just start date (open) transaction per customer per day.
- Flag 'N' only for closed transactions, 'Y' for open i.e. no end date.

**Current set example looks like this:**
Note: for this particular customer we have equal amount of transactions (inserts & deletes so I know the flag will be 'N', when we map start and enddates, but the solution also has to work when there are more start dates than enddates for other customers, where the final (newest) start date row will have a flag of 'Y'.

| Customer_Id | Start Date | End Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 |  | 02/07/2020 20:58:32.000000 | N |
| 111 |  | 02/07/2020 19:18:04.000000 | N |
| 111 |  | 01/06/2020 09:38:49.000000 | N |
| 111 |  | 01/06/2020 09:36:34.000000 | N |
| 111 |  | 29/05/2020 16:58:07.000000 | N |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 20:57:52.000000 |  | N |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 19:17:22.000000 |  | N |
| 111 | 29/05/2020 16:58:06.000000 |  | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:38:40.000000 |  | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:36:34.000000 |  | N |

**Expected result:**

| Customer_Id | Start Date | End Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 20:57:52.000000 | 02/07/2020 20:58:32.000000 | N |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 19:17:22.000000 | 02/07/2020 19:18:04.000000 | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:38:40.000000 | 01/06/2020 09:38:49.000000 | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:36:34.00000 | 01/06/2020 09:36:34.000000 | N |
| 111 | 29/05/2020 16:58:06.000000 | 29/05/2020 16:58:07.000000 | N |

**Partial solution that works for the above example:**

```
select customer_id
  ,start_date
  ,lead(end_date) -- find the next row's end date
   over (partition by customer_id
         order by coalesce(start_date, end_date)) as new_end
  ,case when new_end is null then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag
from tab
qualify start_date is not null -- only return starting rows
order by 1,2;
```

However, in case there are more start dates than end dates (e.g. several closed transactions, one open (can be not only the latest/newest one, but also somewhere in the middle..)) it will not work. E.g. in case a transaction is open: start date 12/01/2019 09:36:34.00000 but no end date
then the lead() skips over this null enddate value and assigns the next available end date, leaving the solution looking like this:

| Customer_Id | Start Date | End Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 20:57:52.000000 | 02/07/2020 20:58:32.000000 | N |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 19:17:22.000000 | 02/07/2020 19:18:04.000000 | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:38:40.000000 | 01/06/2020 09:38:49.000000 | N |
| 111 | 12/01/2019 09:36:34.00000 | 18/11/2019 16:58:07.000000 | N |
| 111 | 18/11/2019 16:58:06.000000 | NULL | NULL |

When it should look like this:

| Customer_Id | Start Date | End Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 20:57:52.000000 | 02/07/2020 20:58:32.000000 | N |
| 111 | 02/07/2020 19:17:22.000000 | 02/07/2020 19:18:04.000000 | N |
| 111 | 01/06/2020 09:38:40.000000 | 01/06/2020 09:38:49.000000 | N |
| 111 | 12/01/2019 09:36:34.00000 | NULL | Y |
| 111 | 18/11/2019 16:58:06.000000 | 18/11/2019 16:58:07.000000 | N |

How to find a solution that fits both cases?

Comment: You want to match DATEs and TIMESTAMP? What is your expected result, and why?

Comment: Changed both to timestamps, added expected result. The reason for expected result - all transactions need to be entered into one row, with a flag.

Comment: The result doesn't match the data, the NULL and the previous row will be switched.

Comment: it does actually, its exactly what im getting when trying to apply the same logic for one missing enddate (this case the missing one would be row 4 (nothing against the 01/06/2020 09:36:34, but the script skips this missing record and imports the next one (29/05..)

Comment: This result is not possible, 29/05/2020 is before 01/06/2020. Must be something else. Btw, if you got a start and an end date with exactly the same timestamp, you might need to add logic what to sort first, e.g. `order by coalesce(start_date, end_date), start_date nulls first)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the matching end date for each start date.

```
select customer_id
  ,start_date
  ,lead(end_date) -- find the next row's end date
   over (partition by customer_id
         order by coalesce(start_date, end_date)) as new_end
  ,case when new_end is null then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag
from tab
qualify start_date is not null -- only return starting rows
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked flawlessly :) :)

Comment: would you have any suggestions for such cases when there are more start dates than enddates? in this case lead blindly continues to move over the NULL enddate and assign the next available enddate, messing up the real transaction timestamps

Comment: Yes, if there are more starts than ends there might be gaps as the lead finds the next row's end timestamp. If you want a different result you should extend your example data with these edge cases and elaborate on the logic. Edit your question or ask a new one.